# Find the Rebus in the Rebus

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle

Find the [image]

> ```
> def That(n):
>     def Question(n): return n+1|-n-2
>     a = Question(n)
>     return a
>
> >>> That(42)
> -1
> ```

### Clarifications

1. **Three hints would be provided every 6 hours unless this puzzle gets solved before the next scheduled hint.**
2. I may not respond to all the comments. The Rebus is quite easy and any hint would make this puzzle vulnerable.
3. There will be one and only one answer.
4. <strike>The first Rebus would be solved in a day.</strike>

**Hints**

Hint1:

> The first hint has been provided. Can you find any difference in the current rebus with the previous?

Hint2:

> The second hint has been provided. Can you identify each of the elements in the first rebus?

Hint3:

> Simple is better than complex.
>  Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

Comment: So, we have to solve 2 rebus, combine them and solve a third rebus?

Comment: @leoll2. Actually you have to solve two rebus but eventually you give get one and only one answer.

Comment: Well, I assume the language the code snippet is written in is Python...

Comment: I assume you didn't do type checking on the function input so that it looked cleaner, right? Or is the fact that this function crashes with non-numeric input relevant?

Comment: @IanMacDonald: Type checking for the input was neither relevant nor necessary. If done so, it would break the puzzle.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I think rebus 1 depicts a python and the characters <"/">.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> "To be, or not to be, that is the question"

because

> That(42) returns a Question whose value is 43|-44 
>  which in hexadecimal is 0x2b | ~0x2b 
>  (where '~' is bitwise NOT and '|' is bitwise OR).

Comment: Wonderful. I knew this was easy, but I would still wait to see if someone is able to solve the first Rebus. Off-course both of the Rebus are related in a way.

Comment: And unless this was evident, by using the parameter 42 I was trying to depict that the answer to life, the universe and everything is actually a question

Answer (score 2):

1)

> Slash's Snakepit

It was an American rock band. In the picture we see a slash inside a snake drawing a "pit" with its body. I think the quotation marks are just there so that people don't confuse the slash with a random line.

2)

> That question got a negative answer

Assuming it's Python, you call the function That() using 42 as parameter. The result is -1, a negative number.

Comment: I fear its not right. Moreover there will only be one and only one answer.

Comment: Well, I just tried :)

Comment: Please don;t be dishertened. Trust me once this get answered you would surely say ohhh this was so obvious

Answer (score 1):

The image rebus has three parts

1. [image] - This refers to [Code](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=code&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Xf9IVb3_BNWcugSfn4HgDg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=667#tbs=isz:i&tbm=isch&q=code&imgrc=_hFfLnkt5l4_TM%253A%3BwooKFzwtWZ-sLM%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fcdn3.iconfinder.com%252Fdata%252Ficons%252Fseo-internet-marketing-flat-icons%252F128%252Fweb-code.png%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.iconfinder.com%252Fsearch%252F%253Fq%253Dcode%3B128%3B128)
2. "" - That refers to quote
3. The Python

Joining them in order: Find the quote in the Python Code

Answer (score 0):

The image represents:

> Shake the spear: Shakespeare.

I guess the answer is: https://youtu.be/xsXKT5RhJf8?t=38